# tomcat catalina log rotation with compress

Tags: tomcat, logging, rotation, compression, catalina

I am using Jira in tomcat. My Catalina.out logs are rotating now with Date. My requirements are below.

1. Keep only 15 days logs ( Catalina.out )
2. Compress logs  the logs after rotation

Could someone please help me for this.

Thanks

Comment: I have found the answer for this.

Comment: Here is the method i have followed in the logrotation

Comment: `/opt/atlassian/jira/logs/catalina.out {
        rotate 5
        daily
        missingok
        notifempty
        dateext
        delaycompress
        compress
        postrotate
                reload rsyslog >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
        endscript
}`